# Why is Contenttemplate null

Tags: wpf, mvvm, itemcontainergenerator, contenttemplate

I am using WPF with MVVM principles.
The view looks like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ValveOptionTemplate" >                
            <Grid Margin="{StaticResource MyApp.DefaultMarginTopBottomThin}" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Center">                        
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                        
               <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
               </Grid.RowDefinitions>

               <myApp:CheckBox Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="0" 
                               Margin="{StaticResource 
                                          MyApp.DefaultMarginTopBottomThin}"
                               IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                               Checked="ToggleButton_OnChecked"/>
               <myApp:TextBox Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="0"
                              Width="300"
                              Margin="{StaticResource MyApp.DefaultMarginLeftThin}" 
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              Text="{Binding Description, 
                                       UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                              IsEnabled="{Binding IsEditable}"                                     
                              x:Name="textBox"/>    
            </Grid>                    
         </DataTemplate>    
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="OptionGrid">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="Options" ItemsSource="{Binding Options}"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ValveOptionTemplate}" 
                      FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" 
                      Margin="{StaticResource MyApp.DefaultMarginTopBottomThin}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Nothing strange i would say. I am trying to access the myApp:TextBox to set the focus on it.
For this i use this (not completed) snippet in code behind (i know what MVVM principles are and i don t think i am violating them).

```
private void ToggleButton_OnChecked( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
   var cp = Options.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as ContentPresenter;        
   var dt = cp.ContentTemplate; //<--this is null! Why?
   var tb = (TextBox)(dt.FindName( "textBox", cp ));           
}
```

You see my comment in the event handler? The contenttemplate is null? Why? What am making wrong?

Comment: Have you subclassed TextBox and CheckBox? Why the myApp:

Comment: @kenny Yes the controls are subclassed.

Comment: @dev hedgehog: dt is null

Comment: Got it, I see now what you up to. Read my answer please.

Comment: Why do you need access to each textBox? What are trying to do?

Comment: I have the same problem when I define the DataTemplate in the window.Resources. When I define it in ItemsControl.ItemTemplate it doesn't return null.

Answer (score 2):

At the point the binding is being evaluated the complete visual tree is not build yet.

That is why template is not available.

In order to fix this you will have to call `cp.ApplyTemplate` or postpone the code to be executed when UI thread is in background by using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`.

Comment: I call that in the UI thread when a button is clicked. But it still returns null.